# Problem with windows on Snow Leopard - won't show more than one window

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard

This is very annoying. Somehow I activated the 'single application' mode on Snow Leopard and it doesn't show more than one window on the desktop.

I've searching for a solution and trying that Terminal fix but it won't work.

Does someone know how can I fix this?

Comment: Snow Leopard doesn't have a "Single Application" mode, as far as I know.

Comment: @Mark-Szymanski Single Application mode only allows one window to be active at a time while the rest are banished to the background... they are still running, just not visible...

Answer (score 2):

Terminal:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock single-app -bool false
killall dock
```

Edit:

Since this does not seem to work for you, I would recommend going into /Library/Preferences in your user folder and deleting com.apple.dock.plist and com.apple.dock.db and it will completely reset your dock since this is where the single-application mode preferences would reside.

Log out / Login or...
Reboot

** You will have to add applications / change prefrences for your dock because it will revert to default**

Comment: I tried that and nothing happens. Is there any preference somewhere in Snow Leopard?

Comment: There is no GUI for the preference... the only option is to change com.apple.dock to have single-app disabled... have you rebooted?

Comment: Yes I have, several times. No luck thought.

Comment: You are using "killall dock" as a separate command (not in line with the rest) correct?

Comment: Yes I am. I'm first submitting write and then the killall for rebooting the dock.